# read data json from a specific url

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, try-catch

i want do display the data inside this url on my node stand out but it display none , there is something i do wrong in my code

```
const extractRefDefaultSchema = async (data) => {
const url = "https://mos.esante.gouv.fr/NOS/TRE_R81-Civilite/FHIR/TRE-R81-Civilite/TRE_R81-Civilite-FHIR.json"
https.get(url,(res) => {
    let body = "";
    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", () => {
        try {
            let json = JSON.parse(body);
            // do something with JSON
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        };
    });
}).on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
});
console.log("extractRefDefaultSchema");
```

};

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for do this :

```js
fetch(url)
.then((res)=> res.json())
.then((json) => {
    let dataJson = JSON.parse(json)
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `.catch()` in case anything bad happens with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with [axios](https://npmjs.com/package/axios), it would be much simpler.

Code:

```js
let axios = require("axios")
axios.get("https://mos.esante.gouv.fr/NOS/TRE_R81-Civilite/FHIR/TRE-R81-Civilite/TRE_R81-Civilite-FHIR.json").then((res) => {
    let jsonData = res.data
})
```